# Split comma separater string while escaping the ones in parentheses

Tags: python, csv, ddl

I am receiving SQL DDL string with embedded commas as well in the values.e.x.

```
org_id bigint,merc_name varchar(50),deposit_day date null,amount decimal(18,3),bank_name varchar(128)
```

These SQL string values are extracted from DDL files which we receive from other app(so, we currently cannot ask the other team to fix it from their end to escape embedded commas). We would want the output to be:

```
['org_id bigint', 'merc_name varchar(50)', 'deposit_day date null', 'amount decimal(18,3)', 'bank_name varchar(128)']
```

I tried the csv module, but that still does not escape the embedded commas in the value. Is regex the only way to go about?

Comment: The CSV module won't handle this, no; in a CSV you'd use quoting around the value to handle this. You'll use a parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
ddl = 'org_id bigint,merc_name varchar(50),deposit_day date null,amount decimal(18,3),bank_name varchar(128)'
print re.findall('(?:[^,(]|\(.*?\))+', ddl)
```

Answer (score 2):

Tokenize and use the simplest of state machines; this'll not handle nested parentheses but it is enough for this case:

```
import re

def parse_sql_ddl(ddl):
    tokens = iter(re.findall('(\w+|[,() ])', ddl))
    current = []
    for token in tokens:
        if not token: continue  # zero-width start or end
        if token == ',':
            yield ''.join(current)
            current = []
        elif token == '(':
            current.append(token)
            for token in tokens:
                current.append(token)
                if token == ')':
                    break
        else:
            current.append(token)
    if current:
        yield ''.join(current)
```

This parses your input into tokens (either word characters, *or* commas, parentheses and spaces, then yields completed column declarations:

```
>>> sample = 'org_id bigint,merc_name varchar(50),deposit_day date null,amount 
decimal(18,3),bank_name varchar(128)'
>>> for column in parse_sql_ddl(sample):
...     print column
... 
org_id bigint
merc_name varchar(50)
deposit_day date null
amount decimal(18,3)
bank_name varchar(128)
```

You can extend the parser to handle error conditions (`current` being empty when there is a comma, or you running out of tokens before you find the closing `)`, etc.). It could also easily be extended to handle quoted names (which could contain parentheses and commas too!), again by adding a nested loop just like the one handling parentheses.